# Limit for replace string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace a string with a limit but I don't get any idea. Someone, please help me. Here is the problem :

Please look above div here like I want to change dummy with dummy2, but no more than 2,  I was able to replace dummy to dummy2 but not limit replacing all,

My code

```js
// replace with title 
var get_parent = $('.single-cat-product-item');

if (get_parent.length > 0) {
  get_parent.each(function() {

    var get_titile = $(this).find('.single-cat-product-list-title h3').justtext();
    var az_link = $(this).find('.Check-Latest-Price-On-Amazon').attr('href');
    var item_content = $(this).find('p');

    item_content.each(function(i) {
      var finalOutput = $(this).html().replace(new RegExp(get_titile, "ig"), '<a href="' + az_link + '" rel="nofollow">' + get_titile + '</a>');
      $(this).html(finalOutput);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-cat-product-item">
  <h3 class="single-cat-product-list-title"> Dummy2 </h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy </p>
</div>
```

Can anyone please give me the solution to limit only two times?

Comment: I doubt that you managed to do it at least once, because `"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).justtext is not a function"`. `justtext()` is not a jQuery method.

Comment: What do you want to happen two times? The `.each()` or the `.replace()` inside it?

Comment: There are so many wrongs things with this code. `'.single-cat-product-list-title h3'` does not exist. It should be `'h3.single-cat-product-list-title'`. `'.Check-Latest-Price-On-Amazon'` doesn't exist. Then you want to replace `' Dummy2 '` (with spaces around) inside the `<p>`, but they don't contain any. Also, checking for `if (get_parent.length > 0)` is useless. This is a complete mess

Comment: @JeremyThille, he was obviously sloppy when creating the [mcve]. It typically happens when you try to cut down a more complex example to a minimal one.

Comment: Yeah, and also we had to edit his question like 4 times, because everything (code + questions) was repeated twice, with bits of code not formatted as code etc.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is your index. Use it:

```
item_content.each(function(i) {
  if (i < 2) {
    var finalOutput = $(this).html().replace(new RegExp(get_titile, "ig"), '<a href="' + az_link + '" rel="nofollow">' + get_titile + '</a>');
  $(this).html(finalOutput);
  }
});
```

See it working here:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var get_parent = $('.single-cat-product-item');

  if (get_parent.length > 0) {
    get_parent.each(function() {
      var title = $('h3', this).text(),
        az_link = $(this).find('.Check-Latest-Price-On-Amazon').attr('href'),
        item_content = $(this).find('p');

      item_content.each(function(i) {
        if (i < 2) {
          var finalOutput = $(this).html().replace(new RegExp(title, "ig"), '<a href="' + az_link + '" rel="nofollow">' + title + '</a>');
          $(this).html(finalOutput);
        }
      });
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-cat-product-item">
  <h3 class="single-cat-product-list-title">Dummy</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy </p>
</div>
```

Comment: or simply `if(i>=2) return;`, this avoids wrapping the code in `{ }`

Comment: @JeremyThille, the brackets are not such a bad thing. Typescript, for example, doesn't even allow un-bracket-ed ifs. As the complexity of the apps one develop grows, the tendency is to stay away from any gimmicks and write more readable and more robust code. That's the main thing that brackets bring on the table: ability to always place a console log before the line, without having to worry the line won't run or will always run.

Comment: but why wrap a whole bunch of code inside brackets when you can avoid it?

Comment: @J, for readability and flexibility in working with said code. First off, brackets are a lot more obvious than a return up above. They typically change alignment in any IDE. And they can also be collapsed easily. How do you collapse the portion after a if-ed return? Besides, the code is skipped anyway. I don't see the gain here. 2 chars? It's way better to parse your production code through a minifier and let it worry about chars size while you write readable code. Code that makes more sense to as many other devs out there. I guess the end reason is brackets fill your pockets faster.

Comment: Indeed. Fair enough